# How to fix jsdom issue from jest on Angular 7?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

When I run test by jest on my angular 7 I got this error

```
console.error node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
          at Object.dispatchError (D:\Subin\PROJECTS\angular-project\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:60:19)
          at Request.client.on.err (D:\Subin\PROJECTS\angular-project\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom-thirteen\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:674:20)
          at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
          at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
          at Request.onRequestError (D:\Subin\PROJECTS\angular-project\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
          at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
          at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
          at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
          at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
          at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7) undefined
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

my setupJest.ts

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';

Object.defineProperty(window, 'CSS', {value: null});
Object.defineProperty(document, 'doctype', {
  value: '<!DOCTYPE html>'
});
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      display: 'none',
      appearance: ['-webkit-appearance']
    };
  }
});
/**
 * ISSUE: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7101
 * Workaround for JSDOM missing transform property
 */
Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupJest.ts"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "diagnostics": false
      }
    }
  },
```

I read this from https://angular.io/guide/testing

That's not a problem when you run the CLI ng test command because it compiles the app before running the tests.

However, if you run the tests in a non-CLI environment, tests of this component may fail

I think it is about I run the test in a non-CLI environment.

What I have tried:

1. tried to run test in a ClI environment with @angular-builders/jest
2. tried to overwrite external file on my app component

My app component spec

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AppComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  test('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to run the tests in a non-CLI environment, if they work there?

Comment: I want to use jest for implement testing on my app so the syntax will run jest is `jest` only without `ng` command so it is not run in CLI environment. I think so it lead me to this issue.

Comment: But... *why*? What do you hope do achieve?

Comment: Dear bro, because jest provides some benefits such as sensible faster; parallelized test runs, snapshot testing, rich CLI options for me, etc...

Comment: I can only see references to Karma, not Jest, in the docs page you've linked to, so it's unclear where you've actually *"read this from"*. That error seems to be referenced in the preset issues only in https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/257. Also, FWIW, snapshot testing is not good testing, although I can see the appeal of parallel test runs and the Jest CLI is nice.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @GuillermoGonzález Yes. I fixed this issue already and now my Angular 8 project is using Jest for testing. But, it is unit test only and I use Cypress to run end to end test. Because my project is very big with more than 25 small repositories inside(mono repo). So it is very slow when run test on Karma.

Comment: thx for the reply, I was able to solve the issue, at the end was only add this to the jest.config.js file

`globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$',
      astTransformers: [require.resolve('jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer')]
    }
  },`